# variable speed control for audio playback in the browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, audio-streaming, html5-audio

Is there a way to change the playback speed of audio in the browser? What is best to accomplish this task, html5 audio, or flash, or something else? Are there any specific libraries that would help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Web Audio API.

In the following code I answered your other question.

[best way to loop audio in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289643/best-way-to-loop-audio-in-the-browser)

Modify the code in my answer above as follows for a playback speed example.

Right below

```
source.loop = loopOnOff;
```

add

```
source.playbackRate.value = 1; // change number to between 0.10 to 10 (or larger/smaller) to test.
```

You can also run the html audio tag through the web audio api and add effects processing.

Comment: This use of ``playbackRate`` isn't working across all browsers.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't. It's only webaudio API enabled browsers.

Comment: Yep. But actually, just having a HTML5 compliant browser should be sufficient. The ``audio`` element supports variable playback rate.

Comment: most browsers accept palybackRates between 0.5 and 4 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/WebAudio_playbackRate_explained)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question there,

HTMl5 will have player speed control will have speed control..

A couple of noteworthy upcoming features are playbackRate and defaultPlaybackRate. As you can probably imagine, these fellas let us alter the speed and direction of playback. This functionality could be used for fast-forward and rewind functions or perhaps to allow users to tweak the playback speed so they can fit more podcasts into their day.

audio.playbackRate returns 1 at normal speed and acts as a multiple that is applied to the rate of playback. For example, setting playbackRate to 2 would double the speed, while setting it to -1 would play the media backwards.
audio.defaultPlaybackRate is the rate at which the audio will play after you pause and restart the media (or issue any event for that matter).

---

Flash Player may help( but it will be customized one you may create, with stream buffer, you need to define the player speed once buffer has the content to play.

Sound easy but will take a lot effort,
Refer VLC opesource for better Idea, its documented with ffmpeg which works with Audio,
and works with client software, in browser ti will be heavy, refer Just to have idea.

I hope this may help :)